# Express and ejs <%= to render a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, express, ejs

In my index.ejs I have this code:

```
var current_user = <%= user %>
```

In my node I have

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.locals.user = req.user
    res.render("index")
})
```

However, on the page I obtain

```
var current_user = [object Object]
```

and if I write

```
var current_user = <%= JSON.stringify(user) %>
```

I obtain:

```
var current_user = {&quot;__v&quot;:0,&quot;_id&quot;:&quot;50bc01938f164ee80b000001&quot;,&quot;agents&quot;:...
```

Is there a way to pass a JSON that will be **JS readable**?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Oh that was easy, don't use `<%=`, use `<%-` instead. For example:

```
 <%- JSON.stringify(user) %>
```

The first one will render in HTML, the second one will render variables (as they are, eval)

Comment: Correct answer but just to precise, it is <%-JSON.stringify(user)%> that render the magic.

Comment: Is the eval function actually used, or are you implying that what results is similar to if eval was called. I'm curious, because as we all know, eval is...

Comment: Ok, so because of my curiosity, I dived into it and discovered that it does in fact use eval(). I should also add that I know it's an often parroted saying and eval isn't necessarily evil, just easily misused. Had to mention that before I inspired some wrath among the masses.

Answer (score 6):

Attention!

If the user can be created through API calls, <%- would leave you with serious XSS vulnerability. Possible solutions can be found here:

[Pass variables to JavaScript in ExpressJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098397/pass-variables-to-javascript-in-expressjs/16098699#16098699)

Answer (score 2):

if like me your object can include an escaped character such as `/` or `"` then use this more robust solution

```js
var current_user = <%- JSON.stringify(user).replace(/\\/g, '\\\\') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work now in Express's latest version

Comment: Which version ?