# Pass variables to JavaScript in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am completely lost on this; I am using NodeJS to fetch a JSON and I need to pass the variable to my page and have JavaScript use the data.

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.render('testPage', {
        myVar: 'My Data'
    });
```

That is my Express code (very simple for testing purposes); now using EJS I want to gather this data which I know to render on the page is simply

```
<%= myVar %>
```

But I need to be able to gather this data in JavaScript (if possible within a .js file) but for now just to display the variable in an Alert box I have tried

In Jade it is like `alert('!{myVar}')` or `!{JSON.stringify(myVar)}`. Can I do something similar in EJS. I don't need any field like `<input type=hidden>` and taking the value of the field in javascript. If anyone can help be much appreciated

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You could use this (client-side):

```
<script>
  var myVar = <%- JSON.stringify(myVar) %>;
</script>
```

You could also get EJS to render a `.js` file:

```
app.get('/test.js', function(req, res) {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
  res.render('testPage', { myVar : ... });
});
```

However, the template file (`testPage`) would still need to have the `.html` extension, otherwise EJS won't find it (unless you tell Express otherwise).

As @ksloan points out in the comments: you do have to be careful what `myVar` contains. If it contains user-generated content, this may leave your site open for script injection attacks.

A possible solution to prevent this from happening:

```
<script>
  function htmlDecode(input){
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    e.innerHTML = input;
    return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  }
  var myVar = JSON.parse(htmlDecode("<%= JSON.stringify(myVar) %>"));
</script>
```

Comment: btw, I managed to get ejs to recognise a .js template by adding this to my server.js app.engine('js', require('ejs').renderFile);

Comment: You can also use some simple ou double quotes surround the code. <%-JSON.stringify(myVar) %>; to "<%- JSON.stringify(myVar) %>;"

Comment: be careful, because if myVar has any user-generate content in it, your site will be vulnerable to XSS attacks

Comment: @ksloan using `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: @robertklep yes, look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/k1x230d8/ (it just send an alert). This works since ```JSON.stringify("</script><script>alert('test')</script><script>")``` returns ```"</script><script>alert('test')</script><script>"``` and the ```<%- %>``` operators *do not* escape the result.

Comment: @ksloan of course, you're right. I edited the answer to point this issue out.

Comment: JSON.parse will fail if myVar has a property with value with unescaped double quote

Comment: I just tested your suggestion with htmlDecode that should prevent XSS. However, unless I'm mistaken, it doesn't seem to work. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a6618gv2/1/

Comment: @Kito it works _iff_ `myVar` is passed as a variable from Express to EJS. Your fiddle skips that step (and in fact throws an EJS exception if used as template).

Comment: If you render without template, can you still pass variables `res.render('test.js', { myVar : ... });`? I'd like to preserve the `js` file extension

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira `res.render()` by definition requires a template, although you can probably set Express/EJS up so that you can use the `.js` extension for templates as well.

Comment: @robertklep according to the documentation of EJS "If the path (of the view) does contain a file extension, then Express will load the module for the specified template engine (via require()) and render it using the loaded module’s __express function." My question is whether there is any simple template for js files or how can I simple render a js file with an absolute path.

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira you can still use EJS to "render" `.js` files, like this: `app.engine('js', require('ejs').renderFile)` (and put the `.js` file in the "views" directory)

Comment: @robertklep thank you so much. And if I want to have my js file in another directory?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira you can change the location of the views directory (or set more than one) using [`app.set('views', ...)`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.settings.table)

Comment: Note that if your dataset is very large, it might be broken up into multiple nodes, and hence e.childNodes with have a length of more than 1. To concatenate the data, use the normalize function, i.e `e.normalize()` on the line before the return statement.

Answer (score 10):

if you have more complex objects like an array, you can do this :

```
<% if (myVar) { %>
   <script>
      myVar = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(myVar) %>');
   </script>
<% } %>
```

otherwise, previous solutions you have seen will not work

Comment: It was working without this `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` trick, but VS Code was showing an "Expression expected" error (even with the EJS language support extension). Now it doesn't anymore =D.

Answer (score 10):

The main difficulty here is to avoid XSS risks if myVar contains quotes, or `</script>` for example. To avoid this problem, I propose to use **Base64** encoding after JSON.stringify. This would avoid all risks related to quotes or HTML tags since Base64 only contains "safe" characters to put in a quoted string.

The solution I propose:

EJS file:

```
<script>
  var myVar = <%- passValue(myVar) %>
</script>
```

which will render into something like (for example here myVar = null):

```
<script>
  var myVar = JSON.parse(Base64.decode("bnVsbA=="))
</script>
```

Server-side NodeJS:

```
function passValue(value) {
  return 'JSON.parse(Base64.decode("' + new Buffer(JSON.stringify(value)).toString('base64') + '"))'
}
```

Client-side JS (this is an implementation of Base64 decoding that works with Unicode, you can use another if you prefer but be careful if it supports Unicode):

```
var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.addEventListener('load', function(){
         alert('<%= myVar %>');
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Heres how i made it work,
in node js pass the json like this

```
let j =[];
//sample json
j.push({data:"hi});

res.render('index',{json:j});
```

now in js function

```
var json = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(json) %>');
```

This worked well for me

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation [here](https://github.com/mde/ejs#client-side-support):

Go to the [Latest Release](https://github.com/mde/ejs/releases/tag/v2.3.3), download ./ejs.js or ./ejs.min.js.

Include one of these on your page, and `ejs.render(str)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the accepted solution JSON.parse will fail if myVar has a property with value with unescaped double quote. So better traverseObj and escape each string property.

Here is a function that covers my case:

```
function traverseObj (obj, callback)
{
    var result = {};
    if ( !isArray(obj) && !isObject(obj) ) {
         return callback(obj);
    }

    for ( var key in obj ) {
        if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
            var value = obj[key];
            if (isMongoId(value)){
                var newValue = callback(value.toString());
                result[key] = newValue;
            }
            else if (isArray ( value) ) {
                var newArr = [];
                for ( var i=0; i < value.length; i++ ) {
                    var arrVal = traverseObj(value[i], callback);
                    newArr.push(arrVal);
                }
                result[key] = newArr;
            }
            else if ( isObject(value) ) {
                result[key] = traverseObj(value, callback);
            }
            else {
                var newValue = callback(value);
                result[key] = newValue;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

Than in ejs you simply has to:

```
<%
    var encodeValue = function(val) {
        if ( typeof val === 'string' ) {
            return sanitizeXSS(val); //use some library (example npm install xss)
        }
        return val;
    }

    var encodedProduct = ejs_utils.traverseObj(product, encodeValue);
%>
```

and now you can transport is safely with unescaped syntax

```
window.product = <%-JSON.stringify(encodedProduct)%>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. i got the value

```
var inJavascript = JSON.parse("<%= myVar %>");
```