# Node.js How to display more than one category of articles on a page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I want to limit how many posts each category can display with a .limit() function and i am not sure how to come by this.

I am using Mongoose and Express.

My code so far is a follows.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  MainArticle.find({ category: ['Worldwide', 'U.S. News'] },  function (err, mainArticles) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render('landing', { mainArticles: mainArticles });
    }
  });
});
```

If i was to output the results with EJS, it will display all the results of both categories. And if i was to limit, it would just limit to the integer i set.

I'm not sure what to pass on so i can display the two articles at different parts of the webpage as well as limit how many posts to show.

---

```
router.get('/profile', function (req, res) {
  // Retrieve the desired count for each category (for example, through a query parameter) defaulting to some number as needed.
  var limit = req.query.limit || 10;

  // Create an object to hold the results
  var result = {};

  // Get data for the world wide category
  MainArticle.find({
      category: ['Worldwide'],
    })
    .limit(limit)
    .exec(function (err, worldwideArticles) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        // Add the worldwide data to the result set
        result.worldwideArticles = worldwideArticles;

        // Get data for the US news category
        MainArticle.find({
            category: ['U.S. News'],
          })
          .limit(limit)
          .exec(function (err, usArticles) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              result.usArticles = usArticles;

              // Hand the two different sets separately to the template
              // You will obviously have to change the template code to handle the new data structure of different categories
              res.render('profile', { result: result });
            }
          });
      }
    });
});
```

---

EJS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var json_data = <%= JSON.stringify( result ); %>
</script>
```

This displays articles for "Worldwide", limited to 10 articles.

```
  <ul>
    <% result.worldwideArticles.forEach(function(mainArticles){ %>
    <li>
      <div class="img-container">
          <a href="/articles/<%= mainArticles._id %>"><img src="<%= mainArticles.image %>" alt=""></a>
           <div class="title-container">
            <a href="/articles/<%= mainArticles._id %>"><%=mainArticles.title %></a>
          </div>
      </div>
     <% }); %>
```

Comment: Look into `filter`. `.find` will return first matching object or null

Comment: To clarify, you want `'Worldwide'` and `'U.S News'` to be set on different key so your landing page?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to query for each category separately and build your result for the template by setting the result of the two `find` operations on different keys in the result.

```js
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // Retrieve the desired count for each category (for example, through a query parameter) defaulting to some number as needed.
  var limit = req.query.limit || 10;

  // Create an object to hold the results
  var result = {};
  // Get data for the world wide category
  MainArticle.find({
      category: ['Worldwide']
    })
    .limit(limit)
    .exec(function(err, worldwideArticles) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        // Add the worldwide data to the result set
        result.worldwideArticles = worldwideArticles;
        // Get data for the US news category
        MainArticle.find({
            category: ['U.S. News']
          })
          .limit(limit)
          .exec(function(err, usArticles) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              result.usArticles = usArticles;
              // Hand the two different sets separately to the template
              // You will obviously have to change the template code to handle the new data structure of different categories
              res.render('landing', result);

            }
          });
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what some would call, callback hell.

Comment: @JosephChambers agreed. The exec method returns a Promise which would be the ideal way to handle this. However, the code posted by OP used the callback feature so I opted to keep the answer in the same format to convey the answer without adding additional complexity.

Comment: oh, yes. That's a good point. Maybe he just doesn't understand my examples which would make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at how I would do it here. Let me know if this works.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  MainArticle
    .where('category')
    .in(['Worldwide', 'U.S. News'])
    .limit(10)
      .then(mainArticles => {
        res.render('landing', { mainArticles })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  )
}
```

You *may* need to have a select here, but I cannot test it. If it doesn't work just add the properties you want to select after the .in. like `.select('name', 'age', 'tags')` or even better `.select({})` but I don't know what will work without testing. I'm just going off documentation here:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/finding-documents.html

Reading the Query API another way to do this would be like this:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const fetchArticles = MainArticle.find({})

  fetchArticles
    .where('category')
    .in(['Worldwide', 'U.S. News'])
    .limit(10)
      .then(mainArticles => {
        res.render('landing', { mainArticles })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  )
}
```

.. or if you want to get fancy:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {

    function getArticles() {
        return MainArticle
            .where('category')
            .in(['Worldwide', 'U.S. News'])
            .limit(10)
            .exec()
    }

    try {
        let mainArticles = await getArticles()
        res.render('landing', { mainArticles })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

UPDATE based on your last commit.

```
  router.get('/', async (req, res) => {

    function getWorldwideArticles() {
        return worldwideArticles
            .where('category')
            .in(['Worldwide'])
            .limit(10)
            .exec()
    }

    function getUSArticles() {
      return usArticles
          .where('category')
          .in(['U.S. News'])
          .limit(10)
          .exec()
    }

    try {
        let worldwideArticles = await getWorldwideArticles()
        let usArticles = await getUSArticles()
        res.render('landing', { worldwideArticles, usArticles })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

Comment: In the post Chirag Ravindra made, he used   result.worldwideArticles = worldwideArticles; and  result.usArticles = usArticles; to help me retrieve these two categories separately. How may i implement this with your method?

Comment: So looking at this again; we're passing everything to main articles and what I would do is on the ejs side check for which category is there which is why you see I'm doing ['Worldwide', 'U.S. News'] 

Just grab me those two in one lookup. It's less expensive. Let me modify my response to make it easier for you. Maybe it will open your eyes.

Comment: @MichaelSanders I think that should work. Let me know if it doesn't, and we can screenshare on skype if you want.

Comment: i get error "getWorldwideArticles is not defined" and its referring to "return worldwideArticles ". And if i comment out the first function, i then get "usArticles is not defined", referring to "return usArticles".

Comment: You may need to do alike: await Promise.all([ getWorldwideArticles(), getUSArticles() ])

it's something silly.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using what Chirag Ravindra posted and passed on

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var json_data = <%- JSON.stringify( result ); %>
 </script>
```

above my forEach statements on my EJS because [EJS can't call variables from clientside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787204/pass-variable-from-express-to-client-javascript)

Then i just used

```
<% result.worldwideArticles.forEach(function(mainArticles){ %>
<% }); %>

<% result.usArticles.forEach(function(mainArticles){ %>
<% }); %>
```

Where i wanted to post the two categories.

Comment: Would you mind pasting your entire route so I can refactor it? :D

Comment: Take a look and let me know if i am missed something. Still new to all this.