# Passing vars from ejs to javascript (server to client on render) while avoiding XSS issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xss, ejs

It seems like the accepted way to pass variables to JavaScript using ejs is like so:

```
<script>
  var foo = <%- JSON.stringify(foo) %>;
</script>
```

But I've ran into XSS issues using this method, and wanted to know if there was a better/safer way.

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/k1x230d8) shows the vulnerability.

This works since `JSON.stringify("</script><script>alert('test')</script><script>")` returns `"</script><script>alert('test')</script><script>"` and the `<%- %>` operators **do not** escape the result.

It also works for objects: [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/n354ofjm)

```
<script>
var test = {
    "text": "</script><script>alert('test')</script><script>"
}
</script>
```

Is there a safer way to handle this?

Comment: Feeling (partially) responsible for this question being asked, I updated my answer to include a possible solution. Feel free to scrutinize it :-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/16098699/893780

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Base64** encoding after JSON.stringify. This would avoid all risks related to quotes or HTML tags since Base64 only contains "safe" characters to put in a quoted string.

The solution I use in my website:

EJS file:

```
<script>
  var foo = <%- passValue(foo) %>
</script>
```

which will render into something like (for example here foo = null):

```
<script>
  var page = JSON.parse(Base64.decode("bnVsbA=="))
</script>
```

Server-side NodeJS:

```
function passValue(value) {
  return 'JSON.parse(Base64.decode("' + new Buffer(JSON.stringify(value)).toString('base64') + '"))'
}
```

Client-side JS (this is an implementation of Base64 decoding that works with Unicode, you can use another if you prefer but be careful if it supports Unicode):

```
var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a simpler alternative to Base64 encoding you can also use the native JS functions `encodeURI()` and `decodeURI()`. They escape `<script>` tags and quotes properly and even support unicode characters.

Your script would then look like this:

```
<script>
  var foo = JSON.parse(decodeURI("<%- encodeURI(JSON.stringify(foo)); %>"));
</script>
```

and setting `foo = "</script><script>alert('test')</script><script>"` would lead to following HTML source generated by EJS, which is perfectly safe:

```
<script>
  var foo = JSON.parse(decodeURI("%22%3C/script%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('test')%3C/script%3E%3Cscript%3E%22"));
</script>
```

Like Raphaël mentioned, you could also define a server side function to call from EJS to simplify this process if this is used more often.

```
function passValue(value) {
  return 'JSON.parse(decodeURI("' + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(value)) + '"))';
}
```