# can not parse escaped ejs passed variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, ejs

this is my current problem, so i passed stringified array to client from server and i was trying to get it with following code

```
const stringifiedArray = "<%= array %>";
```

and it was returning string but when i was trying to parse it, it was returning JSON error "Unexpected Token in position N" and when i changed double quotes with backquote and equation sign with minus sign:  (backquote)`<%-array%>`(backquote)
it worked and parsed perfectly, but what is i wanted escaped string to be parsed? how can i do that?

Comment: Is `"<%- JSON.stringify(array) %>"` what you're looking for?

Comment: no, i am stringifying array in server side and i am looking for parsing it in client side

Comment: Is the code you provided server-side code or client-side code?  I would expect on the server you would embed the `JSON.stringify`-ed version into a rendered script tag.  And on the client, it just uses the rendered script, no parsing necessary.  So I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing vars from ejs to javascript (server to client on render) while avoiding XSS issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262022/passing-vars-from-ejs-to-javascript-server-to-client-on-render-while-avoiding)

Comment: Try printing that variable out to a comment in your ejs template. For example:
`// <%= array %>` We need to see what the actual value you are trying to embed within quotes is.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
const stringifiedArray = <%- JSON.stringify(array) %>;
```

instead of

```
const stringifiedArray = "<%= array %>";
```

and do not stringify your object or array at server side