# Access variable defined in <% %> from <script> </script>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ejs

I pass a variable `title` to my html document and access it there like this:

```
<h2><%= title %></h2>
```

How can I access the same variable inside the `<script>` tag? 
I tried the following but it gives me an error:

```
<script>
    console.log(title);
</script>
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: title is not defined

Is this because the variable is in a different scope?

**EDIT:**
I wanted to keep things simple in this post but based on the answers I realize that I should have mentioned that I use an external file for my script:

```
<script src="/javascripts/script.js"></script>
```

In this script I use jQuery for some stuff and I need the variable `title`there.

Comment: Are you using ejs templates?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access template variables in rendered output due to the nature of templates. However, you could *render* a javascript variable of the same name that is set to the literal value of the template variable. For example:

```
<script>
  var title = <%- JSON.stringify(title) %>;
  console.log(title);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not quite what I need. I thought stuff inside the tag would be evaluated the same way as if I did it in an external file. Your solution does not work in my external file: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Why can't you place the suggested template partial *before* your `<script src="/javascripts/script.js"></script>`? Then your `/javascripts/script.js` should have access to `title` just fine due to (global) scoping (assuming that you're rendering the output that contains `<script src="/javascripts/script.js"></script>` and it's not from a static file being served).

Comment: I tried this, but it does not compile there either.

Comment: What does "it does not compile" mean?

Comment: My editor says expression expected and if I run it anyways it says in the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Then it sounds like you're not rendering that output, you're serving it up as a static file. You would need to call `res.render('htmlWithTitleVariable', { title: 'foo' })` whenever a client requests that html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107639/discussion-between-aedug-and-mscdex).

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do something like this as [shown is this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098397/pass-variables-to-javascript-in-expressjs).

```
<script>
  var title = <%- JSON.stringify(title) %>;
</script>
```

Comment: This does not compile for me :(

Comment: Read the accepted [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098397/pass-variables-to-javascript-in-expressjs). Depending upon how you've configued express/ejs you may need to approach it differently.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access the same variable inside the `<script>` tag?

You can't. Variables in a program running on the server cannot be access by a program running on the client.

Since you have **copied** the value of the variable into the DOM of the page, you can read *the value* it held from there.

```
console.log(document.querySelector('title').firstChild.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I defined it like this -

```
<body>
<h2 style = "visibility:hidden" id = "events"><%= events %></h2> 

<script>

function initMap (){

var list =document.getElementById('events').innerHTML ;
      console.log("list = ", list)
}
</script>
```