# How to access fields of a CouchDB document

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I have defined a `permits` field for a couchdb document like below. I cannot access `permits` content by `*.permits.db` I wonder if anybody knows how I can do that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of your problem is that the value of the `permits` attribute is badly formatted. You have a `string` rather than an object.

Change:

```
"{db: ['TEL', 'PPT',]}"
```

With:

```
{"db": ["TEL", "PPT"]}
```

Please note that if your JSON is not formatted correctly (see [JSON specification](http://json.org/)), it will be automatically turned by CouchDB admin interface into a string. Therefore remember:

- to use **double** quotes around object keys,
- to use **double** quotes around object values,
- not to use a **comma** at the end of an array.

Comment: Or, use a JSON library rather than encoding it yourself.