# how to create function like in php in node js

Tags: php, html, node.js, ejs

actually i have used functions like as follow

```
function selectBloodGroupNames()
{
    return array("A+", "O+", "B+", "AB+", "A-", "O-", "B-", "AB-", "A1+Ve", 
    "Unknown");
}
```

the above function return list of blood group which can be formatted as per our idea like to display in a drop down or else in a table!!!

i have saved that function in a separate file called functions.php

how to use the same like in node.js in express module and in ejs or basic html template engine.

Comment: Are you asking how to create and populate an array in JavaScript? Ie `return ['A+', 'O+', 'B+', 'AB+', ...]`

Comment: no exactly like that, actually i am planning to create function that has to called globally in every pages of project in node js

Comment: So you want a .js file that you can include in every of your other js files, as with PHPs include() ?

Comment: yup, @Zim84 and not only in js, i am using ejs template engine in node js for my project, so i need that idea to be done on the ejs template engine tooo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for using in node.js you can create a separate file common.js

```
 module.exports=function selectBloodGroupNames()
 {
    return ["A+", "O+", "B+", "AB+", "A-", "O-", "B-", "AB-", "A1+Ve", 
    "Unknown"];
 }
```

then in the file you want to use it you can include it and use it like below:-

```
   const Common=require('pathto/common.js');
   let bloodGroupList= Common.selectBloodGroupNames();
   //now you can use it where ever you want 
   console.log(bloodGroupList);
```

Comment: what if i have function such as the below, how do it work?

`function successMessage($message)
{
    echo 
    '
        <div class="alert pastel alert-success" align="center">
            <p>'.$message.'</p>
        </div>
    ';
}`

Answer (score 2):

Full Example with access array in *ejs* file

**data.js**

```
 const sampleArray = {
     function1(){
     return ["A+", "O+", "B+", "AB+", "A-", "O-", "B-", "AB-", "A1+Ve", 
        "Unknown"];
      },
   function2() {
     return ["A+", "O+", "B+", "AB+", "A-", "O-", "B-", "AB-", "A1+Ve", 
        "Unknown"];
     }
    }
module.exports = sampleArray;
```

**main.js** //render ejs file.

```
const  sampleArray = require('./data');
app.get('/renderEjs', function(req, res) {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
  res.render('ejsHtmlFileName', { myArray :sampleArray.function1(),myArrayTwo:sampleArray.function2()});
});
```

**ejsFile**

```
<div><p><%= myArray %><%= myArrayTwo %></p></div>
```

Reference Link for render data in ejs file - [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098397/pass-variables-to-javascript-in-expressjs)

Comment: Your ans was exaclty matching my point!

But i am using more than one function in the **data.js** and i will use those functions n number of functions in the **viewes.ejs** file, so i cannot define every function during the time of rendering in the **main.js** file!

Comment: I have update my answer please check..You need like this?

Comment: The ans was good! your have answered what i expected, but it is like hard coding will not be automated, if there was 10 to 15 functions have to add in the **view.ejs** file! i need to define the 15 function in the **main.js** file during rendering and also i have to do it for many page during rending, This will increase the lines of code! in the **main.js** file!

Comment: Now second time i have update my answer  Please check

Comment: You are not getting my point @IftekharDani. u are defining for every function!

{ myArray :sampleArray.function1(),myArrayTwo:sampleArray.function2()}

what i am asking is if there are 20 to 25 function how can we define it! thats what my que?

for a single page if we define 25 times means! think about other pages! if there are 50 pages, i need to pass 25 functions for each of the 50 pages individually! so a simple code as like php call a line like '<?php required('functions.php'); ?>' and the functions.php returns those 25 functions for each 50 pages!

Answer (score 0):

you should install babel to able of use ES6 for javascript

`npm install --save-dev babel-core`
then you create separate file config.js. In config.js :

```js
export default Config {
  selectBloodGroupNames() {
     return ["A+", "O+", "B+", "AB+", "A-", "O-", "B-", "AB-", "A1+Ve", 
    "Unknown"];
  }
}
```

then in file you want to use function

```js
import Config from ./pathto/config.js;

function functionName () {
  var arr = Config.selectBloodGroupNames();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At last i found an solution myself with the answer referencing from **@IftekharDani** and done some changes myself

**functions.js** the file which contains multiple functions!!!

```
module.exports = {
    menuTop: function(){
        var data = '<li>'+
        '<a href="/login">Log in</a>'+
        '</li>'+
        '<li>'+
        '<a href="/register">Register</a>'+
        '</li>';
        return data;
    },

    workCheck: function(user){
        if(user === "OLD")
        {
            var data1 = '<h1>OLD user</h1>';
        }
        else
        {
            var data1 = '<h1>Unknown or new user</h1>';
        }
        return data1;
    }
};
```

**app.js** main rendering file where i pass the entire file with the variable to the ejs file

```
var func = require('./functions');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('home', { funs : func});
});
```

**home.ejs** file that contains the function's content.

**function 1**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <%- funs.menuTop(); %>
</ul>
```

**function 2**

```
<div class="row">
    <%- funs.workCheck("NEW"); %> 
    /* Here i pass parameter to the function that i call from the external file to which make more dynamic. */
</div>
```

and finally i get the expected result! i will give 50% credits to **@IftekharDani** for giving me an idea. Thank you!