# Accessing MongoDB Data in a <script> tag

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm passing MongoDB data into my EJS file. I can access the data using the `<% %>` tags in my HTML. The issue I'm running into is I need to access the data inside my `<script>` tag and the `<% %>` tags no longer work.

Things I've tried:

Adding the data to a hidden input and accessing it with `document.getElementById().value`

I've tried researching any examples of using mongo data in a script tag but most answers are related to `<% %>` in HTML/EJS

locationSchema

```
const locationSchema = new Schema({

    lat: String,
    lng: String,
    title: String

});
```

app.js

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){

    Locations.find({}, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.render.status(500).send('<h1>ERROR</h1>');
        } else{
            console.log(results)
            res.render('homePage',{results, Locations, req});
        }
    });
});
```

ejs

```
<!-- ejs_views/homePage.ejs -->

<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">

<!-- displays head.ejs-->
<head>
    <% include head %>
    <style>
        #map{
            height:400px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<!-- displays header.ejs-->
<body class = "container">
<header>
    <% include header %>
</header>

<!-- Edit the body of the front end here-->
<main>
    <div class = "jumbotron">
        <h1>This is great</h1>
        <p>Testing out EJS</p>
    </div>
    <div id = "map"></div>

    <% for (const location of results) { %>
        <h1> <%= location.title %></h1>
        <h1> <%= location.lat %></h1>
        <h1> <%= location.lng %></h1>
    <% } %>

    <script> 
        function initMap(){

            //SYNTAX ERROR HERE ON <% AND %>
            const locationResults = <% JSON.stringify(results) %>;
            //Map Options to dictate zoom and position
            var options = {
                zoom: 16, 
                center: {lat:35.6543936, lng: -97.4714266}
            }
            //init map for view
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

            /*var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position:{lat: 35.654243, lng: -97.472937 },
                map: map,
                title: 'Math And Computer Science'
            });*/

            //addMarker({coords:{lat:35.6543936, lng: -97.4714266}, title: "TestCase"});
            //iterateFunc();
            results.forEach(location => addMarker({coords: {lat: location.lat,lng: location.lng}, title: location.title}))

            //Add Marker Function
            function addMarker(props){
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: props.coords,
                    map:map,
                    title: props.title
                })

            }
        }
    </script>


</main>
<!-- displays footer.ejs-->
<footer>
    <% include footer %>
</footer>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAftGHvJnejXQm5k1jiLiBRsRwm5SXqzm8&callback=initMap">
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Expected results:

able to loop through the mongodata in my script and use it in the addMarker function

Actual results: :[

Comment: What do you mean with "<% %> tags no longer work inside html tags"?

Comment: Inside the script tag. I guess S.O deleted "<script>" from my post.

Comment: I also tried the solution on this post with no success https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098397/pass-variables-to-javascript-in-expressjs/16098699

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. In your app.js file render `results` as JSON string like this.

```
res.render('homePage',{results: JSON.stringify(results)});
```

Now in your homepage.ejs use this:

```
const locationResults = <%- results %>
```

Note that it may cause some errors like "Expression expected .js" in your IDE. Just ignore it. Probably is VS Code compatibility with `ejs` files

Comment: I replied to another answer that my problem is I cannot use <% %> tags inside my script tags at all. It returns a syntax error. Not sure of the cause but maybe something in my ejs is causing this problem so i added the full(but short) ejs to the main post

Comment: First, you forgot `=` in your JSON.stringify assignment. Second, use `forEach` on `locationResults` and not on `results`.

Comment: I appreciate the help,I had already tried that changed, but without sounding like a broken record even with these changes there is the syntax error, caused by the <%= %>. Everyone example I see uses these in the script tags with no flaw.

Comment: Same issue occurs. Do you think adding a <input type = "hidden" id = "locationResults" value = <%- results %>> Outside of the script tags would work?

Edit: it didn't work

Comment: try `const locationResults = JSON.parse('<%- results %>')`

Comment: So I saw your comment about the IDE causing the error. So I tried all the solutions so far  and they compiled and ran. I used the forloop ```           
            <% for (const location of results) { %>
                addMarker({coords:{lat: <%= location.lat %>, lng: <%= location.lng %>}, title: <%= location.title %>});
            <% } %>
```

and it compiles but did not add the markers to the map. (yes the database is populated)

Comment: Then the problem is inside the `addMarker` function. Make sure, that `props` are well defined.

Comment: addmarker function works properly if I hard code numbers and title. I tried

 ` addMarker({coords:{lat: <%= location.lat %>, lng:<%= location.lng %>}, title: <%= location.title %>}); ` 

I output the data and it's able to be printed to the console using <% console.log( location.lat) %> successfully and typeof to show the correct types

Answer (score 0):

I would just write the variable out and use it in the function

```
<script>
const locationResults = <%= JSON.stringify(results, null, '\t\) %>;
// Now you don't have to loop in the template, you can loop on the client
locationResults.forEach(location => addMarker({ coords: {lat: location.lat, lng: location.lng}, title: location.title }));
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear on the problem at hand. Anytime I try and use <%= %> inside of the script tags I get a syntax error "JS expression expected". So either I need to figure out why it isn't accepting the tags or I need another way to use my data inside the script. All examples so <% %> working inside. I will add the full EJS file so clarity.