# How to pass string from EJS Into script tag

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I want to store and print a variable (string in this case) sent from ejs by console.log in script tag

but it gives me an "(index):19 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'text' before initialization"

code in node js

```js
app.get("/", (req, res)=> {
    res.render("index", {message: "hello world"})
})
```

code in html

```html
<script>
   const text = <% message %>
   console.log("message is " + text);
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass variables to JavaScript in ExpressJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098397/pass-variables-to-javascript-in-expressjs)