# How to pass variables to JS with ExpressJS?

Tags: express, ejs

I'm using express & ejs.

I have this route:

```html
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {data: 123})
}
```

**My goal** is to pass `data` into my `public/index.js`

My index.ejs:

```html
<html>
...
...
  <script>
    var myVar = <%- JSON.stringify(data) %>
  </script>
</html>
```

**The error:** syntax error in my IDE: "Expression expected"

I used the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098397/pass-variables-to-javascript-in-expressjs/37920555#37920555), but it's not working.

[image]

Comment: Typo?  Shouldn't the EJS syntax be: `<%= ... %>` instead?  (Note the `=` where you're using `-` in your code.)

Comment: @David, yes you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering with `Salim Baskoy's` code a bit, I found a solution:

inside index.ejs I changed this:

```html
<script>
   var dataVariable= '<%= data %>'
</script>
```

to this:

```html
        <script>
          var dataVariable = '<%- JSON.stringify(data) %>';
        </script>
```

Then inside index.js, I parsed the string back to object using:

```html
JSON.parse(dataVariable)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `JSON.stringify`. You can use the variable you sent as it is. There is a `Syntax error` in your code.
It should be `<%- JSON.stringify(data) %>`  ->  `<%= data %>`

express js

```
res.render('index', {
    data: 123,
  });
```

ejs file

```
  <script>
    var dataVariable= "<%= data %>"
  </script>

    <h2>Variable</h2>
        <p><%= data%></p>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it's still giving me a syntax error. I added a screenshot for reference

Comment: `var dataVariable= '<%= data %>'` try this

Comment: The code compiles now, but how do I then parse the data back into an object inside public/index.js? 

I tried this:

const init = () => {
    console.log(dataVariable); // [object][object]
    console.log(JSON.parse(dataVariable)) // unexpected character at line 1
}