# Why a render object can be display on html but not inside a script?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I passed my 'posts' object to HTML this way.

```
res.render('post', {posts : items });
```

I can access my object inside HTML using this call, and it will display "John"

```
<h1><%=posts[0].name%></h1>
```

However, if I use the same 'posts' object in html but this time put it inside a script for query.

```
<script>
    var data = <%=posts%>;
    for (var i=0, i<data.length, i++) {
      //My intention is to insert a dynamic html code based on this query   
    {
</script>
```

My browser always points to <%=posts%> where I assign 'data' variable for the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier". It shows arrays of [object, Object], [object, Object].....and posts[i].name does not get print out.

So my question is if I can access it directly on html, why put it inside a  tag will result as an error?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Are you using EJS?

Comment: @dan - yes, I am using ejs

Comment: This should help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13788335/4774345

Comment: @dan - Thank you so much. You made my day! I have been searching long time on this, I guess I am not using the right key words.

Comment: Ha, good! :) No problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var data = <%=posts%>;
```

You can use:

```
var data = <%- JSON.stringify(posts) %>;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. That solved my problem.