# How to trim empty space in the center of a string?

Tags: javascript

I have dynamically generated `JSON` file with data. Some of the data generate error of an invalid `json`:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 34447 column 24 of the JSON data
```

I located problems and some of these are

```
"live_href": "http://   http://google.com",
or
"login_pass": "bourdfthuk.midas.admin   r3adqerds7one",
```

I already fixed whitespace at the beginning and end with `.trim()` but trim won't remove whitespace in the center of a string.

Comment: `.replace("\s", " ")`?

Comment: Thing is, the spaces in that string wouldn't make the JSON invalid...

Comment: Instead of "fixing" the JSON before parsing, fix the generation on the server.

Comment: @Andreas, yes I'm trying to fix it before it populates on the server. I'm using nodejs ejs file to do that

Comment: @Bergi, that didn't help.

Comment: @user184994, test it here https://jsonlint.com/ and you will see it does!

Comment: @Katerpiler I just did, and as long as it's wrapped in braces so it knows it's an object, it's perfectly valid

Comment: As already mentioned there is something wrong with the way you create it.

Comment: @user184994, show me the valid json with whitespace how you're suggesting because it is giving me an error on that site

Comment: @charlietfl, any idea how to define it so it translates as string even with whitespace?

Comment: No idea unless you show how source is created. Can have unlimited  spaces in a string and wouldn't affect json validity if it is properly created and stored

Comment: @Andreas, I actually needed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13788335/3498491

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you are trying to do. In that case, you will have to loop through your string like so:

```
var word = "North Dakota       Blah blah";
word = word.split(' ');
for (var x = 0; x < word.length; x++) {
    if (word[x] === "") {
      word.splice(x, 1);
      x--;
  }
}
word = word.join(' ');
console.log(word);
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/85sj4ay6/2/

Answer (score 4):

Use this

```
str.replace(/\s/g,'')
```

The g repeats for all whitespace instances and the s is for all white spaces and not just the literal characters.

Comment: Actually no, this doesn't work correctly. It makes json valid but it removes all spaces which makes other things wrongly formated. I have site names like "North Dakota Server Site" and that becomes "NorthDakotaServerSite".

Answer (score 0):

As someone already mentioned, your json is invalid, so you therefore cannot parse it into JSON. However, if it was valid, it would essentially work like this:

```
var myJson = {"login_pass": "bourdfthuk.midas.admin   r3adqerds7one"};

myJson.login_pass = myJson.login_pass.replace(/ /g, '');
console.log(myJson);
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/85sj4ay6/