# Loading an inline script in a Node.js template, then sending it to the client

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, server-side-rendering

I'm running a simple Node.js server, and I have a function defined that I want to load as in inline script (in an HTML file/template) and then send that template to the client. I guess this is essentially basic Server Side Rendering (SSR)?

I'm not sure how to go about this though... I though it would be really simple but am having some trouble. I've tried templating with EJS but have not have any luck so far. But I'm pretty new to EJS and server side templating some I may be missing something really simple.

This is the type of code/template I'm trying, where `initUser` is the function I want inline:

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('test-template', {
    initUser: initUser,
  });
});
```

```
  <body>
    <h1>An EJS template</h1>
    <script>
      ('<%= initUser %>');
    </script>
  </body>
```

But then in the browser after I hit the end point and look in the elements tab of dev tools this is what I see:

```
<script>
  ('[object Object]')
</script>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I feel like this should be relativity simple and I'm probably missing something obvious but I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Try changing to: `initUser: JSON.stringify(initUser)`

Comment: Then an empty object ```{}``` is inside the script tag

Comment: Have you checked if the response has data

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean... I want the entire function loaded inline, not just a return value. The function uses things like cookies and utm params in its logic, so I need the whole thing to run on a client.

Comment: Check if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788314/express-and-ejs-to-render-a-json

Comment: That sounded promising but I still get an empty object when I try ```<%- JSON.stringify(initUser) %>``` in the template :(

Comment: So as I tried to explain, the problem must be in your response: returning { } (that's why it is rendered)

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? And just to be clear on what I'm looking for, I want the actual function passed to the client, I don't want to execute this function on the server.