# EJS not showing only some variables

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have this ejs template:

```
<h1 id="city-name"><%= title %></h1>
<h5 id="weather-description"><%= description %></h5><br>
<i class="bi bi-thermometer-half"></i><p id="temperature"><=% temperature %></p><br>
<i class="bi bi-wind"></i><p id="wind"><=% wind %></p><br>
<i class="bi bi-moisture"></i><p id="humidity"><=% humidity %></p>
```

and this is my js:

```
jsonObj = res.data;
desc = jsonObj.weather[0].description;
temp = JSON.stringify(jsonObj.main.temp);
wind = JSON.stringify(jsonObj.wind.speed);
hum = JSON.stringify(jsonObj.main.humidity);
console.log(wind);
console.log(temp);
console.log(hum);
response.render('city_template.ejs', {title : nameCapitalised, description : desc, temperature : temp, wind : wind, humidity : hum});
```

but in the template it shows only the title and the description, not the other variables, in console it shows wind, temp and hum, what's wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13788335/7974050

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your tags are incorrect.

For example, `<=% temperature %>` should be `<%= temperature %>`